# How to stop using Time Capsule as router?

Tags: network, wifi, time-machine, airport, router

I have a Comcast router XB-6T and it's supposed to be better/faster than using my Time Capsule/802.11ac as a router. I'm on a iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6.

Currently I thought I was using my TC as a router in bridge mode (however the Comcast guy set it up and the TC says bridge mode off).  I am not very hardware literate but I'd like to make sure I'm using the Comcast router.  We do have Ethernet cables plugged into the back of the TC that goes to other rooms/devices and one USB on the back of the TC that goes to a printer.

I'd like to know if someone can give me instructions how to no longer use my TC as a router and instead use the Comcast router. I'd like to keep the same Network Name and would also need to know if I need to move any/all of the Ethernet cables from the back of the TC and plug them into the Comcast router instead; I don't know if there is enough availability.

Currently the back of my TC the slots are all full. If it makes more sense not to mess with it then I won't. Can someone advise what would be best to do and how to do it?

Comment: Consider carefully the decision to use your ISP's router. You are better off putting the ISP's router into bridge mode, and using your existing router to provide ips to your network. Why? Because ISP's regularly do things like this:  https://alexandrevvo.medium.com/cve-2020-29138-improper-access-control-in-the-sagemcom-router-model-f-st-3486-running-net-4-109-0-797968e8adc8 They don't patch firmware. They backdoor your network. Bridge their router and use one you control.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Comcast router XB-6T and it's suppose to be better/faster than using my Time Capsule/802.11ac as a router.

Better/faster is very subjective.  You need to define what "better" and "faster" mean to you.  But for comparison:

- Both are 802.11ac devices
- Both have Gigabit WAN connection (the XB-6 claims "a maximum" of 1 GB throughput)
- Both have Gigabit Ethernet ports.  Apple has 3, Xfinity has 2
- Both have dual band (2.4GHz and 5GHz) radios

So, from a performance perspective, there's really nothing that stands out.

> We do have Ethernet cables plugged into the back of the TC that goes to other rooms/devices and one USB on the back of the TC that goes to a printer.

Whether or not you have Ethernet cables plugged into the TC or the XB really doesn't matter.  The TC is plugged into the XB (it must be if you have Internet) then regardless of which device you plug into, they're all Gigabit, so there's no advantage to doing this.  The XB6 doesn't mention USB, so you'll want your TC to act as a print server.

> I'd like to know if someone can give me instructions how to no longer use my TC as a router and instead use the Comcast router but also I'd like to keep the same Network Name

In order to configure your Airport Time Capsule, you need the Airport Utility and related documentation:

- [Airport Utility 6.3.1 for Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1664?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
- [Airport Utility 5.6.1 for Windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1547?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
- [Airport Utility Users Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/aputility/welcome/mac)

We don't know and cannot support your Xfiniti device.  If you want to use that device with the same name as your Time Capsule, you'll need to consult their support options.  That said, if you wish to use their WiFi, you have to make sure the WiFi on the TC is either

- turned off; or...
- set up in "client mode".

There's detailed information on how to do this in this [Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056).  If this is not something you're good with and/or don't know how exactly you want it configured, I highly suggest getting a local tech person to come out and set this up. There's simply too many variables for a succinct answer in this medium.  Additionally, there's no way of knowing how the XB is configured to properly advise you how to configure the TC.

**Bottom Line....**

If WiFi on your TC is working fine, then there's no reason to change.  In other words, if you're satisfied with the performance, there's no need to do anything.  If you want to maximize the efficiency and coverage of your WiFi, you need to bring in someone familiar with this kind of work.

Comment: Wow that was a very thorough answer and I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me understand everything, which I now do!

Comment: Great involved answer - a few brief points from my experience with both the XB6 and the Time Capsule: User25570 has the Time Capsule configured properly for this with Router Mode "Off". The only thing to consider is Allan's comments regarding WiFi. I would also go with his advice to turn off one or the other device's WiFi feature. XB6 has some very nice security features and parental control options to pause devices and such that the Time Capsule currently does not have. Time Capsule does printer sharing, which XB6 does not, and backups. So in your shoes, I would turn Wifi off on Time Capsule.